# Facebook getting the stars on the auth request

Tags: facebook, review

this might be a simple question but I can't find any info on it, I'm looking for a way to show a star rating when an application on facebook is requesting access.

On the request for permission page the stars show under the app title

Any help with this would be appreciated

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday' 
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens automatically, you don't need to do anything